# ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_tree' from 'sklearn.tree'

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

Import error when importing plot_tree from sklearn

after doing **pip install sklearn**

Error-Log:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier, plot_tree

ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_tree' from 'sklearn.tree'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install scikit-learn

Fix:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 2):

Plot tree is available after sklearn version > 0.21.

```
pip install --upgrade sklearn
```

could help but if it isn't you have to upgrade whole python version.

I had the same issue on 3.6.7 python
and solve it by installing 3.7.7.